# obj-c iOS TensorFlow Lite using GPU delegate with MoveNet Lightning model failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpu, tensorflow-lite, coreml

I'm using TensorFlow Lite and I'm attempting to use a GPU processing delegate with the move net multi-pose model.  The interpreter initialization fails with an ambiguous error.  I'm attempting to use the Core ML GPU delegate but in the code below.  I've tried TFLMetalDelegate as well and that fails as well.  I'd be happy if ANY GPU processing would work with TFL.

This is the link to the model:
https://tfhub.dev/google/movenet/multipose/lightning/1

```
NSError* error = nil;
TFLInterpreterOptions* options = [[[TFLInterpreterOptions alloc] init] autorelease];
options.numberOfThreads = 4;
    
TFLCoreMLDelegateOptions* mlOptions = [[[TFLCoreMLDelegateOptions alloc] init]autorelease];
TFLCoreMLDelegate* coreMLDelegate = [[[TFLCoreMLDelegate alloc] initWithOptions:mlOptions] autorelease];
    
NSArray* delegates = [NSArray arrayWithObject:coreMLDelegate];
    
_interpreter =  [[TFLInterpreter alloc] initWithModelPath:[NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"movenet_lightning_multipose" ofType:@"tflite"] options:options delegates:delegates error:&error];
```

The error returned says:

Error Domain=org.tensorflow.lite.interpreter Code=4 "Failed to create the interpreter." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to create the interpreter.}

Using CPU processing is incredibly inefficient and very slow.  Is there anyway to use GPU processing with the movenet model on the iPhone?

Thanks for the help!!